# how are functions made global in php across modules?

Tags: php, function, spl-autoload-register

Iam going through some legacy `php` codebase. I having difficulty understanding how functions are made global in php. Here is the directory structure of the project.
The functions defined in `GlobalUtilities.php` are available in `Profile.php` without any `include_once(../../../GlobalUtilies.php)`. How is it so?

```
PHPProject
     com.example.usermanagment
             includes
                    GlobalUtilities.php
             controller
                    Entrycontroller.php
             model
                 classes
                         com
                             example
                                     user
                                         resources
                                                    Profile.php
```

But there is this file `autoloader.php` included in `GlobalUtilies.php`.

```
`autoloader.php`

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $classFile = dirname(__DIR__)
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'model'
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes'
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';

    if (file_exists($classFile)) {
        include_once($classFile);
    }
});
```

I looked at document for `spl_autoload_register` and my understanding is that it is NOT making functions global here

`GlobalUtilies.php`

```
require_once('autoloader.php');
......// rest of functions here
```

**EDIT**:
I just noticed that the php tag is not closed in `GlobalUtilities.php`. 
That is , I see only this `<?php` and NO `?>`.
will that make the functions defined in this file available globally.

Comment: The autoloader loads Namespaced Classes i believe.

Comment: Well, while `Profile.php` might not include `GlobalUtilities.php`, it's possible that `Profile.php` might be included in a file that also includes `GlobalUtilies.php`, maybe something like `index.php`. In that case, it'd be able to see the functions.

Comment: @JazzCat Yes, but PHP currently lacks function autoloading.

Comment: @Andrea: I looked at the `profile.php`. It has only namespace and other `use statements` for importing classes . but no `include` or `require` of any kind

Comment: Is this a framework?

Comment: As noted, there is no autoloading of functions, only classes. However, any function that is defined in any file is globally scoped, meaning that you include the file once and the functions inside are then globally scoped. You can also define a function in a class, and that function will then be globally accessible once that part of the code is called: http://3v4l.org/HW8ke -- if I had to guess, I would assume that there's some kind of bootstrap that would include `GlobalUtilities.php`, which makes any function therein globally scoped.

Answer (score 0):

`spl_autoload_register()` makes function as `__autoload()`. This means that if you try to use an undefined function it will try to include it from other included namespace you use. So if you just have included 'autoloader.php' in `GlobalUtilies.php`, and you use a namespace like `com\example\user\resources\Profile`, it will automatically include `Profile.php` and all it's functions, like configured in autoload function.

```
    ...
    include_once($classFile);
    ...
```

Comment: If there's a function in the class file, yes, this would explain it.

Comment: @Andrea: there is no functions in the class file. I am importing functions from `globalUtilities.php`. This has all the functions available and somehow 'magically' available across all modules

Comment: I think it would be better, if you show some code from `GlobalUtilies.php` and `Profile.php`, not only `autoloader.php`. Otherwise everyone can only imagine how it could work.